# How to convert preg_replace to preg_replace_callback for php7

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

I am working on migrating a php website and getting the following statement

"preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback".

When changing to preg_replace_callback, I get an error message "preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, '$this->('\1')', to be a valid callback".

### Code:

```
function getFile($filename)
{
    if ($filename{0} == '/' && substr($this->fileRoot, -1) == '/') {
        $filename = substr($filename, 1);
    }

    $filename = $this->fileRoot . $filename;

    if (!($fh = @fopen($filename, 'r'))) {
        $this->err[] = PEAR::raiseError(
            $this->errorMessage(IT_TPL_NOT_FOUND) . ': "' .$filename .'"',
            IT_TPL_NOT_FOUND
        );
        return "";
    }

    $fsize = filesize($filename);
    if ($fsize < 1) {
        fclose($fh);
        return '';
    }

    $content = fread($fh, $fsize);
    fclose($fh);

    return preg_replace(
        "#<!-- INCLUDE (.*) -->#ime",
        "\$this->$getFile('\\1')",
        $content
    );

} // end func getFile
```

---

```
    /** change from preg_replace to preg_replace_callback */
    return preg_replace_callback(
        "#<!-- INCLUDE (.*) -->#ime",
        "\$this->$getFile('\\1')",
        $content
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

see this little code to be sure is preg_replace_callback().

```
 <?php
// this text was used in 2002
// we want to get this up to date for 2003
$text = "April fools day is 04/01/2002\n";
$text.= "Last christmas was 12/24/2001\n";
// the callback function
function next_year($matches)
{
  // as usual: $matches[0] is the complete match
  // $matches[1] the match for the first subpattern
  // enclosed in '(...)' and so on
  return $matches[1].($matches[2]+1);
}
echo preg_replace_callback(
            "|(\d{2}/\d{2}/)(\d{4})|",
            "next_year",
            $text);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you everyone, I got it to work. Here's the updated codes.

Comment: return preg_replace_callback(

            "#<!-- INCLUDE (.*) -->#im",

            function ($m) { return $this->getFile($m[1]); },

            $content

Answer (score 0):

**First** as you error message show the variable `$this->$getfile` does not exist anywhere.You must review this part of the code.

**Second** Based on your code and your usage of `$this` we can deduce that your function is a `non-static method`.So in your case a valid `callback` could be an `array` of `object`(as the first entry) and a method(as the second entry)
In your case the `array` should be `[$this,"name_of_your_method_here"]`

Take a look at [callbacks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) for more informations.